# Spree Commerce: minimum order value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

We want to define a minimum order value (depending on the selected shipping method) in our Spree commerce shop.

The only thing I could find regarding this is https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/2786, but 
this is considerably out-of-date; the `Spree::ShippingMethod#available?` method does not even exist anymore.

So how can a minimum order value be enforced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

https://gist.github.com/momolog/7708256

It works, but is not pretty, especially the fixed number in code.
Turned into a spree preference value this could be integrated into spree core, but the maintainers decided against doing so: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/spree-user/xyzwVK-6zgo